# What C# data structure should I use to map a varying number of key/value pairs to a list of strings?

Tags: c#, data-structures, key-value

Let's say I want a list of all the addresses in my neighborhood. And I also want to associate a friend's name and phone number if they live at any of the addresses. But not every address has a friend living there, as complete strangers live at many of the addresses, but conversely more than one friend may live at a single address.

To summarize, I need both a list of addresses, as well as associations to all of those strings in the form of a name/phone# pair for any friends who live at those addresses. The index for searching on this data is only the address, I don't need to access the info by name or by phone number, but I would like to iterate through that data if an address has friends living there.

What is the best C# data structure to use in this situation, and could you perhaps give me some sample code showing it implemented? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dictionary class is your best choice. I'd also create a helper class for storing the Name/Phone # key-value pairs, even though you can use one of the native KeyValuePair or Tuple classes. In the end, code would look like this:

```
class ContactInfo
{
   string Name;
   string TelephoneNumber;
}

Dictionary<string, ICollection<ContactInfo>> addressAndPeopleLivingThere = 
    new Dictionary<string, ICollection<ContactInfo>>();

addressAndPeopleLivingThere.Add("1 Some Street", new List<ContactInfo>());
addressAndPeopleLivingThere["1 Some Street"].Add(new ContactInfo { Name = "Name", TelephoneNumber = "000-000-0000" });
```

Comment: how do I iterate through each ContactInfo class' properties, to output their values to the console for example? I have no problem doing this for the Dictionary's key, but what about each class I'm creating? This is what I've got for the keys:

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ICollection<ContactInfo>> kvp in addressAndPeopleLivingThere
{
     Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
}

Comment: kvp.Value returns the ContactInfo object associated with that key, so kvp.Value.Name and kvp.Value.TelephoneNumber give you access to those properties

Answer (score 1):

You should create the types representing your domain.
Something like:

```
public class Address{
  public string StreetName{get;set;}
  public List<Person> Friends{get;set;}
}
public class Person{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Phone{get;set;}
}
```

then you manipulate in lists.

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>;

    var addWithFriends = from c in addresses where c.Count > 0 select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want an `ILookup<string, Friend>` or a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Friend>>`, which basically amounts to the same thing. Since you want to include all the addresses, construction will be a little more complicated than a simple `ToDictionary` or `ToLookup`, but it's not too bad:

```
var friendsByAddress = friends.ToLookup(f => f.Address);
var addressesWithFriends = addresses.ToDictionary(
    a => a,
    a => !friendsByAddress.Contains(a) ? Enumerable.Empty<Friend>() : friendsByAddress[a]);
```

Using this is simple enough:

```
var friendsAtAddress = addressesWithFriends[address];
foreach(var friend in friends) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @soster: Watch out! LINQ is addictive. Once you start using it, you'll always wonder how anybody ever programmed without it. ;-)